# Remove unit (Mb/s) from values in Grafana

Tags: azure, grafana

I have a graph in Grafana derived from Azure Monitor metrics. In this case a firewall showing throughput in (Mb/s). An example of a value being "3.00 Mb/s". Having the text in the output and not having the field as a numerical one prevents the use of features such as Thresholds.

Is there a ways to use Transforms using "Rename by Regex" to try and remove the " Mb/s" bit but I've had no luck.

Comment: Are you saying that the value is a string instead of a number? Could you add some images to illustrate the situation?

Answer (score 1):

Try the Transformation "Convert field type" and convert the String to a Number.

Documentation: [Grafana docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transform-data/transformation-functions/#convert-field-type).